# React Native Image, Source vs Default Source

Tags: image, react-native

I am new to react native. When I try to display images, there was some glitch when loading the image when I did this:

```
<Image
    style={{width: 100, height: 35, resizeMode:'contain'}}
    source={require('./images/someImage.png')}
/>
```

Then someone suggested me using `defaultSource` instead of `source`. The glitch was gone. So `defaultSource` will do the caching？

The description of defaultSource looks confusing to me on facebook document. What's the best way for you to cache an iamge or display an image?

I am thinking the best way maybe convert the image into a string data so the app doesn't need to download the image anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultSource` seems to be an iOS only property. If the image source is remote, a local image can be specified in defaultSource. That image will be displayed till the remote image gets loaded up.

Caching can be done by specifying the cache property in source:

```
source={{ uri: '', cache: 'force-cache' }}
```

More info can be found in the [ImageSourcePropType](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageSourcePropType.js) in react-native repo.